# TextClock causes ScrollView to jump - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

- I have created a tabLayout that swipes between two fragments using a viewPager2 + Fragment State Adapter
- Within Fragment 2, I have a TextClock within a scroll view.
- When I scroll down to the bottom of the page, it keeps jumping to the top if the page
- [Video link showing issue](https://youtu.be/HOhlVkG9Ky0)

Any help would be appreciated

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".BarcodeFragment">

Xml Code:    

    <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="104dp">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextClock
                    android:id="@+id/simpleTextClock"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:format24Hour="HH : mm : ss"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorDark"
                    android:textScaleX=".94"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:fontFamily="@font/tlcircular_bold"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/box02"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/box02"
                    android:layout_width="329dp"
                    android:layout_height="283.99986dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="450dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/box_rounded_ticket"
                    android:shadowColor="#00FF0A0A"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Java Code:

```
</**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class TicketFragment extends Fragment {

    public TicketFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ticket, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}>
```

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

Whenever configuring the height / width of a TextClock - never use 'wrap_content'. I had to reverse engineer my entire app to find such such a simple problem.

My question is: why has this never been flagged before?!